Invalid preprocessor directive include inside variadic macro
In C I wanted to use preprocessor directives inside a macro. Since this doesn't work, I stumbled over this answer about variadic macros, where a macro accepts a varying amount of arguments.
The answer contained following example:
#ifdef FOO
#define IF_FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__ 
#define NO_FOO(...)
#else
#define IF_FOO(...)
#define NO_FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif

IF_FOO(
  #define BAR 5
  int foo = BAR;
)
NO_FOO(
  #define foo 5
)

As you can see, there's a #define inside IF_FOO, which compiles without errors. However when I use #include it still compiles but the is underlined red (see below). I use the following code:
#ifdef HW_TEST
    #define IF_HW_TEST(...)                 __VA_ARGS__
#else
    #define IF_HW_TEST(...)                 /* ignore */
#endif


IF_HW_TEST(
    #include "hwTesting.h"
    TestMain();
    return;
)


What's the reason for this, or am I missing something?
I use Eclipse (Renesas e2 Studio) and the CC-RL compiler.

The problem is that macro expands as #include "hwTesting.h"  TestMain(); and so on. That's an invalid #include. I think you should take a step back from this and ask a question about the best way to solve the actual problem you are dealing with.

"which compiles without errors" Well yes, but does it actually do what you think it does? (Big hint: nope).

I think example of the answer you are referring is incorrect. C17 standard (draft) §6.10.3 p11 says "If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within
the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined."

Yes it was indeed wrong.. Thanks for the hint.
